# CSS file, couldn't remove borders and fix styling

Tags: html, css

I received this file from my teammate but we didn't know to change few things, this web page looks splits to me and I want to make it look more put together as one page with two borders only, one of them in the title (title would be in the middle on it) and the second one will be where the url input and output are.
this is what ours looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olj6b.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZEeQ.png)

and this is a reference what I want it to be like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM6V4.jpg)

I have the codes for both pages, this is the main:

```
<?php
echo"
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Fake URL Detection </title>
    <style>

        Body {
            font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background-color: #D6E0E2;
            align-content: center;
        }
        button {
              background-color: #4CAF50;
              width: 100%;
              width: 512px;
              padding: 15px;
              margin: 10px 0px;
              border: 10px;
              border-color: darkblue;
              cursor: pointer;
              align: center;
              font-size: 30px;
              font-weight: 900;
              color: black;
              border: 4px solid black;
              background-color: #F4EFE6;
              color: black;
              padding: 14px 28px;
              cursor: pointer;
              border-radius: 10px;
              margin:0 auto;
              display:block;
              margin-top: 32px;
       }
        form {
            border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
        }
        input[type=text] {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 8px 0;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px solid green;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        button:hover {
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
        .txt {
            padding-right: 32px;
            padding-left: 10px;
       }
        .container {
            padding: 5px 128px;
            background-color: #5E6C5B;
        }
        p.solid {
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: green;
            padding: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: white;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body> ";


    $input_url = '';
    $pre_result = '';
    $rf_c = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['rf_c'])){
        $rf_c = $_POST['rf_c'];
        $urlLine = $_POST['urlLine'] ;
        $input_url = $urlLine;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){

        $input_url =  $_POST['input_url'] ;

        if($input_url!=''){
            $predic = '';

            $url = $input_url;
            $clas = '';

            if($rf_c==0){
                $predic = shell_exec('python RandomForestClassifier.py ' . $url);
                $clas = ' Using RandomForest Classifier';
            } elseif ($rf_c==1) {
                $predic = shell_exec('python ExtraTreesClassifier.py ' . $url);
                $clas = ' Using ExtraTrees Classifier';
            }

            if (substr($predic,1,1) == 0) {
                $pre_result = '0 = Benign' . $clas;
            }elseif (substr($predic,1,1) == 1) {
                $pre_result = '1 = Defacement' . $clas;
            }elseif (substr($predic,1,1) == 2) {
                $pre_result = '2 = Malware' . $clas;
            }elseif (substr($predic,1,1) == 3) {
                $pre_result = '3 = Phishing' . $clas;
            }
        }
    }

echo"
        <form method='post'>
        <center> <h1> Fake URL Detection </h1> </center>

            <div class='container'>
                <label><b>URL : </b></label>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Enter URL' name='input_url' value='$input_url' required>
                <input type='hidden' name='urlLine' value='" . $input_url . "'>
                <br>
                <label><b>Result : </b></label>
                <p class='solid'  name='pre_result'>$pre_result</p>

            </div>
            <div class='container'>
                <div style='height:100%; width:100%;'>
                    <button type='submit'  name='btn_submit'>Check URL</button>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <p><b>PLease Select Classification Pickle:</b></p>

                        <form>

                            <input type='radio' name='rf_c' value='0'" ; if($rf_c == 0) echo " checked" ; echo "  onClick='javascript:this.form.submit();'>

                            <b><label for='rf_c'>RandomForest-Pickle</label><br></b>

                            <input type='radio' name='rf_c' value='1'" ; if($rf_c == 1) echo " checked" ; echo "  onClick='javascript:this.form.submit();'>


                            <b><label for='et_c'>ExtraTrees-Pickle</label><br></b>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>

<div class='container' id='the whole thing' style='height:100%; width:80%; overflow: hidden;'>

    <div id='leftThing' style='float: left; width:25%; background-color:oceanblue;'>
        <a class='txt' style='color:#FFFFFF;'><b>0: Classified as Benign</a>
    </div>
    <div id='content' style='float: left; width:25%; background-color:darkgreen;'>
        <a class='txt' style='color:#FFFFFF;'><b>1: Classified as Defacement</a>
    </div>
    <div id='rightThing' style='float: left; width:25%; background-color:pink;'>
        <a class='txt' style='color:#FFFFFF;'><b>2: Classified as Malware</a>
    </div>
    <div id='rightThing' style='float: left; width:25%; background-color:#555555;'>
        <a class='txt' style='color:#FFFFFF;'><b>3: Classified as Phishing</a>
    </div>
</div>

    </body>
    </html>  ";

?>
```

help.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to remove the borders around each section and make the page more cohesive. You can achieve this by modifying your CSS styles. Here's how you can do it:

1. Remove the borders: It seems like the borders come from your CSS style's `border` property. If you want to remove the borders, you can set `border: none;` for the relevant elements.
2. Make the page look more cohesive: To make the page look more put together, you can use CSS to style the elements to fit together better. This might involve adjusting margins and padding, changing colors to match each other, and using consistent fonts and font sizes.

```css
body {
    font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #D6E0E2;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #5E6C5B;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#theWholeThing {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#theWholeThing div {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}

#leftThing {
    background-color: oceanblue;
}

#content {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

#rightThing {
    background-color: pink;
}

#rightThing:last-child {
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

In this code, I've removed the `border` property and added other styles to make the page more cohesive. I've also used flexbox in the `#theWholeThing` div to distribute the child divs evenly.

If the second part of the page moved to the left after adding the CSS, it might be due to the `float: left;` property in the CSS rules for `#leftThing`, `#content`, and `#rightThing`. The `float` property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it.

If you want the elements to be centered, you can replace the `float: left;` with `margin: auto;` in the CSS rules. This will center the divs within their parent container.

Here's how you can modify the CSS:

```css
#theWholeThing div {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

This will center the divs within the `#theWholeThing` div. Adjust the CSS as needed to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do thank you. I added your codes but that moved the second part of the page to the left, is this normal?